# Network arithmetic, finding the next host for the given

Tags: beginner, haskell, networking

Disclaimer: It's literally the second time I write in Haskell.

The purpose of this module is to provide some basic operations with IP addresses (and networks).

At the moment I only implemented the `successor` operation, that returns a next address in the range if it exists.

Eg: for `192.168.1.1` in `192.168.1.0/24` it would return `Maybe 192.168.1.1`

And for `192.168.1.255` (which is the last valid IP address in the given network) it would return `Nothing`.

```
module Main where

import Data.IP (IPv4, AddrRange(addr), fromIPv4, toIPv4, isMatchedTo, makeAddrRange)
import Data.Bits (shiftL, shiftR, (.|.), (.&.))
import Data.List (foldl')
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import qualified Safe as S

parse :: String -> Maybe IPv4
parse = readMaybe

toInt :: IPv4 -> Int
toInt i = foldl' accum 0 (fromIPv4 i)
    where accum a v = (a `shiftL` 8) .|. v

fromInt :: Int -> IPv4
fromInt i = toIPv4 $ map (\s -> (i `shiftR` s) .&. 0xff) [24, 16, 8, 0]

addressesInNetwork :: AddrRange IPv4 -> [IPv4]
addressesInNetwork i = takeWhile (`isMatchedTo` i) adds
    where net = toInt $ addr i
          adds = map (\s -> fromInt $ net + s) [0..]

successor :: Int -> IPv4 -> Maybe IPv4
successor r a = S.headMay $ dropWhile (<= a) $ addressesInNetwork $ makeAddrRange a r


net24 :: IPv4 -> Maybe IPv4
net24 = successor 24


main::IO()
main = print $ parse "192.168.1.201" >>= net24
```

What I don't like: it just looks terrible. I look on it and see Perl, not Haskell.

Have I done something idiomatically wrong or my sense of beauty is broken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you've missed is the [`Enum` instance for the `IPv4` datatype from `iproute`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/iproute-1.4.0/docs/Data-IP.html#control.i:IPv4). Using methods from `Enum` and `Bounded` you can eliminate the use of `Data.Bits` in your code.

Because `IPv4` is `Enum`, your `toInt` method is just `fromEnum :: (Enum a) => a -> Int`. And similarly your `fromInt` is `toEnum`.

`addressesInNetwork` is largely the same logic, you just let someone else do all the work.

```
addressesInNetwork :: AddrRange IPv4 -> [IPv4]
addressesInNetwork range = takeWhile (`isMatchedTo` range) [low..]
    where
        (low, _) = addrRangePair range
```

I would use `addrRangePair` instead of the `addr` field accessor for two reasons. First, `addr` doesn't show up in the Haddock documentation for `Data.IP` which is a bit confusing. Second, on the off-chance that the author of `iproute` begins hiding the constructors of `AddrRange` from export (which is very common practice in Haskell so that library authors can change implementations without breaking users' code) you'll be safe from breaking changes.

Knowing the `Enum` instance and available `Data.IP` functions, you can now write a clearer version of `successor`. Unfortunately we have to be a bit cautious of bounds, `Enum` throws an exception if you try to get the successor of `maxBound`, but it's not too bad.

```
successor :: AddrRange IPv4 -> IPv4 -> Maybe IPv4
successor range ip | ip == maxBound              = Nothing
                   | succ ip `isMatchedTo` range = Just $ succ ip
                   | otherwise                   = Nothing
```

Notice I changed the type signature of your function to take an `AddrRange` instead of a mask length. This is kind of a separation of concerns issue, `successor` doesn't care about the mask length, what matters is whether an IP falls within the range it defines. So `net24` would be implemented as—

```
net24 :: IPv4 -> Maybe IPv4
net24 ip = successor (makeAddrRange ip 24) ip
```

(That's kind of a strange name though, maybe `successorMask24` instead?)

Comment: "That's kind of a strange name though" --- It's actually an artifact from experiments, that I decided to not drop :-)

Comment: After reworking my code I can tell - it's a super valuable answer (I don't have anything "own" left in my code though, but it's okay)

Comment: Haha well the easiest code to maintain is no code at all. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a digit to the integer converted by `toInt` and then convert it back into an IPv4. I couldn't find any generic library in haskell to do this. The one closest to this was `showIntAtBase` in Numeric. I modified it

```
showIntAtBaseGeneric base toChr concat n0 r0 
  | base <= 1 = error ("Numeric.showIntAtBase: applied to unsupported base " ++ show base)
  | n0 <  0   = error ("Numeric.showIntAtBase: applied to negative number " ++ show n0)
  | otherwise = showIt (quotRem n0 base) r0
   where
    showIt (n,d) r = seq c $ -- stricter than necessary
      case n of
        0 -> r'
        _ -> showIt (quotRem n base) r'
     where
      c  = toChr (fromIntegral d)
      r' = concat c  r
```

Now:

```
λ> let foo = succ $ toInt (toIPv4 [192,0,2,1])
λ> showIntAtBaseGeneric 256 id (:) foo []
[192,0,2,2]
```

You can then use the libraries to convert into an IPv4 and check if this is in the valid range (and accordingly return Nothing or Just IPv4).

Note: `showIntAtBase` can be implemented using `showIntAtBaseGeneric` trivially (as shown below). I don't know if this would qualify as useful though :/

```
showIntAtBase :: (Integral a, Show a) => a -> (Int -> Char) -> a -> ShowS
showIntAtBase base toChr n0 r0 = showIntAtBaseGeneric base toChr (:) n0 r0
```